# Can I store a phone number in Smart Lock?

Tags: google-smartlockpasswords

Based on the Google Developers site, it looks like apps can store emails and passwords into Smart Lock.  Is there a way to also store phone numbers in Smart Lock?  Very important for messaging apps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can store any string as the identifier when constructing a credential object, including phone numbers and general usernames, not just email addresses. Ensure to store any phone number in a format your app understands and can use when you retreive it from the API; identifiers will not be normalized in any way.

Example on Android (similar for web):

```
String phoneNumber = "+1 (650) 253-0000"; 

Credential credential = new Credential.Builder(phoneNumber)
    .setPassword(password)
    .build();

Auth.CredentialsApi.save(apiClient, credential).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback() {
            public void onResult(Result result) {
                Status status = result.getStatus();
                if (status.isSuccess()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "SAVE: OK");
                    // updates to existing credentials will succeed immediately
                } else if (status.hasResolution()) {
                    // confirmation is required to save a new phone number
                    status.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SAVE);
...
```

Note that if your phone number-based accounts don't have passwords, you could set the "account type" to your own URL instead of password for the credentials (i.e. `.setAccountType(YOUR_URL)` when building a credential).

See the developer docs for [saving](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/store-credentials) and [retrieving](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/retrieve-credentials) credentials with Smart Lock for more information, and leave any follow-up questions in the comments.